# PageListPager no overload takes 4 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am trying to insert next and previous buttons in the pagination bar

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, PageIndex => Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), new { PageIndex }), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), new PagedListRenderOptions() { LinkToNextPageFormat = "Next", LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "Previous", DisplayLinkToNextPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded })
```

It is throwing the above error.

Previously without `next` and `previous` it was working fine.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, PageIndex => Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), new { PageIndex }))
```

But I need to insert them. 
How to do it?

Comment: Remove the `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()` argument - its not clear what your attempting to do with that. For some examples of typical usage - refer [pagedlist_mvc_examples.cshtml](https://gist.github.com/troygoode/1053136)

Comment: @StephenMuecke That solved it, Thanks a lot! :)